# R eigenvalue matrix diagonal matrix output to csv file

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I have get the covariance matrix of my data set `Usedata`. And I also get the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues and output from R and save it as csv .

I cannot see each variables name at the top of csv file, instead, it just shows me "X1","X2", etc. . I want to see the variable name at the top of each column so I can see which variable has the biggest eigenvalue.

My code:

```
Usedata <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0.244012404, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 
             0, 0), X2 = c(52.72564729, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
             X3 = c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0.142522511, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0), X4 = c(0, 
             0.341103073, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0), X5 = c(0, 0, 
             0, 0, 5, 0.091644475, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0)), .Names = c("X1", 
             "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), class = "data.frame", 
             row.names = c(NA, -12L))

smallcov <- cov(Usedata) 
lam <- eigen(smallcov)$values 
LamM <-diag(lam) 

diagresult <- data.frame(LamM) 

write.csv(diagresult, file = "myoutput.csv")
```

Comment: The csv I can see like this :       X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 52.72564729 0 0 0 0
2 0 0.341103073 0 0 0
3 0 0 0.244012404 0 0
4 0 0 0 0.142522511 0
5 0 0 0 0 0.091644475
6 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: could you check the colnames(LamM) ?

Comment: when you take eigen() you will lose the variable names because its not based on the variables but the entire dataframe

Comment: Your code works and gives the correct output. Your question is: How do I get variable names for the eigenvalues? I suspect you are not too familiar with eigen values and linear algebra. What joel.wilson says is correct. Another way to put it is that eigen values cannot be assigned to a single variable name.

Comment: @joel Wilson, I check the colnames it shows NULL.

Comment: @Ken S.5. I am absolutely familiar with eigenvalues and eigenvector. So, I want to find the most biggest eigenvalue and the variable name of it. But I am not familiar how to coding it in R to write the function myself. So, I have to use the function eigen() already in R

Comment: the biggest eigenvalue is not associated to a single variable. It is associated to the maximum variance direction right. So we can't just assign a single variable name to it.

Comment: To be correct, the largest eigenvalue indicates the variance ("information richness") of the first principal component. A principal component a linear combination of the initial variables and all principal components are perpendicular to each other, or -in other words- the principal components are rotated axes of the initial axes system. You cannot assign one of the initial variable names to an eigenvalue, it wouldn't make any sense: those two things are not related